# Is there a non-recursive '--no-install-recommends' for 'apt-get install'?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dependencies

The apt-get manual says

```
 --no-install-recommends
       Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency
       for installing. Configuration Item:
       APT::Install-Recommends.
```

If I understand correctly, this applies recursively, i.e.
`apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends` skips both the packages `ubuntu-desktop` [recommends](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop) and, recursively, the packages that its dependencies recommend (?)

Is there a simple way of saying 'install ubuntu-desktop, skipping only the packages it directly recommends (but not those recommended by its dependencies)'?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ubuntu-desktop` is a dummy package that installs only its dependencies (size of the .deb  file is 3616 bytes). It will not work standalone.

But if you insist, there is a way, installing it through `dpkg`.

1. Download a package:

   ```
   apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop | grep ^Filename
   wget http://"your repo server directory"/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-desktop_x.xxx_amd64.deb
   ```

   "repo server directory" can be 'archive.ubuntu.com' for example.
2. Use dpkg to install:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-desktop_x.xxx_amd64.deb
   ```

   That will install package without configuring.

Comment: I'm afraid, my use of the term 'dependencies' was misleading. I do want to include the packages listed under 'depends' on https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop, but not the ones listed under 'recommends'. I will adapt the question.